# Get and set PHP variable based on anchor clicked

Tags: php, html

Is there a way to get a certain value and store it in a variable when an anchor linked to a div is clicked?

Like if I have two links like

```
<a href="#one">One</a>
<a href="#two">Two</a>
```

Would I be able to somehow get if the user clicked `one` or `two` and store it in a PHP variable?

Comment: You can do this with jQuery

Comment: you are use Ajax for this task

Comment: Why you want to store that in PHP variable for use that value in next page?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add them as a `GET` request and store it in the session. Change your code this way:

```
<a href="?name=one">One</a>
<a href="?name=two">Two</a>
```

And in the PHP, you can do this way:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["name"] = $_GET["name"];
?>
```

Comment: This solution changes behaviour. Yes, you will submit GET-params to your script, but you lose anchor functionality.

Comment: So should they use AJAX then.

Comment: AJAX would be good, the standard way is fine as well. depends a bit on the actual solution behind.

Answer (score 0):

Take Praveen Kumar's solution and change the HTML part this way to keep anchors working:

```
<a href="?name=one#one">One</a>
<a href="?name=two#two">Two</a>
```